# Draw number like placeholder.com with golang

Tags: image, go, text, draw

I want to create an image with dynamic size like placeholder.com, below is the code to create image with golang:

```
width = 350
height = 150
img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height))
for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        img.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{204, 204, 204, 1})
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

But I want to draw the `width x height` the same as bellow:

[image]

I have researched but the results did not match my requirement. For example, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299930/how-to-add-a-simple-text-label-to-an-image-in-go) only draw text with fixed size and **the text does not look sharp**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a simple text label to an image in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299930/how-to-add-a-simple-text-label-to-an-image-in-go)

Comment: It did not match my requirement

Comment: I agree that the answer to the proposed duplicate should do what you want. Include the code that draws the text as well.

Comment: Sorry for not good at explanation. I didn't just ask about how to draw the text, it's about how to draw dynamic size text as sharp as placeholder.com.

Comment: Try the second answer to the question in the above link. The library he uses allows you to specify the size of the typeface. You need to calculate the size based on the size of the output image.

Comment: @dev.bmax Yeah I'm trying https://github.com/jaredchu/go-image-place-holder/commit/59defd8410a47b29df03d4f9380c478680b96f07